# Websphere 8.5 overlapping jars between project and default server jars

Tags: websphere-8

I have a project deployed on websphere 8.5. However, there are certain classes that are creating conflict due to jar version errors in project and the ones provided by websphere default.

Can anyone help to point mechanism to resolve conflict.

I have  done something similar in weblogic which provides option in welogic.xml to exclude / include jars from project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the use case for the "isolated shared libraries" feature in the WebSphere server.  For any technologies for which you need to bring your own version rather than use the version provided with the server, place the necessary jars into some directory outside the application, create a shared library pointing to that location, select the "use an isolated class loader" option in the library configuration, and associate the library with the application(s) that require it.  The application will search the isolated library class loader before delegating to its parent loaders, and classes there will be found instead of server-provided versions.

A few cautions: This should ONLY be used for technologies that you are 100% certain that you need your own version rather than the server's.  The "parent last" style of class loading used by isolated shared libraries includes some risk of conflicts between class loaders, and avoiding it (by using APIs provided by the server) is generally the safer option.

Note, too, that not everything can be overridden.  The Servlet, EJB, and JPA APIs, for example, will break application startup if included in an isolated shared library, because the server containers require consistent versions of the API classes when processing application objects.  Also, you cannot bring an API of any technology without an associated implementation - doing that is usually a recipe for a VerifyError or LinkageError caused by duplicate visibility to multiple versions of the API.